# Entity framework generic repository - Foreign key exception updating entity relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have followed a EF repository pattern that I read about in Julie Lermans book Programming Entity Framework: Dbcontext

I have an entity called Customer which has a many to many relationship with entity Favourite

Here is some example code of an update to Customer

```
customer.CustomerLocation_ID = 5;     

customer.Favourites.clear();

customer.State = State.Modified;
customerRepository.InsertOrUpdate(customer);
```

Insert will then do the following:

```
Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

foreach (var entity in this.ChangeTracker.Entries<IEntityState>())
{
    IEntityState stateInfo = entity.Entity;
    entity.State = StateHelpers.ConvertState(stateInfo.State);
}
```

Then finally:

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

On save I get an unique key exception on Favourites because Favourites name is unique. But I am not adding anything into Favourites.

When I remove the .clear() line, everything saves fine.

Update:

I added in this piece of code just trying out a few things and now it works.

```
foreach (var fav in customer.Favourites)
{
     fav.State = State.Modified;
}
```

Does it mean that even though I am affecting the Customer I still need to mark the Favourites as modified so they are tracked and updated? I just didn't think I would have to do this.

Comment: You're causing a cascade of deletes from your customer regarding those cleared favorites (in effect, you're saying delete all favorites link records associated with this customer). Are you sure that is the intended effect?

Comment: That's the idea. I want to delete all of a customers favorites. Going to update the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Entity Framework, it should be as simple as doing this:

```
using(var myContext = new MySiteDbContextClassName())
{
     var selectedCustomer = myContext.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerId == someCustomerId);

     if(selectedCustomer != null)
     {
          selectedCustomer.Favorites.Clear();
          myContext.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

If that is not working, then it sounds like something with your configuration / mapping is wrong, and you'll need to check out your configuration.

Comment: If I was to do it that way, then it would work fine. But I am using a repository pattern which involves sending an Entity into this function and then a Unit of work looks after saving changes from all the repository work.

Comment: If your context is always available then, and you only call `SaveChanges` at the very end, it's still the same amount of code. You don't have to muck around in the state management stuff the context is doing under the hood. The context is keeping track of the favorites being cleared, etc

Comment: Cheers Tejs, I'm gonna go away and think for a min. Because I don't have access to the Context and I am working with a new context when saving changes it made sense to use the repository pattern.

Comment: Your answer was helpful because I realised I was not using the repository in the correct way. I should have deleted all relationships Favourites, saved it and then added the new ones. In my situation the context is available, but I would have been receiving the entity from a different system which had modified it under a separate context which is why I unforunately have to do my own state tracking. But.. I've now since changed some of the system architecture to use the context change tracking when possible. Sorry for the delay.